# Email header with custom CC in format: "Name <email>" in php

Tags: php, email

## Question:

How do I get an email header to have a CC with the format: "name <email>"? (I have not found much to help with this when its not the TO or FROM address)

## Summary of Issue:

An email CC field in the format: "name lastname " produces a header like: "name@emaildomain; lastname@emaildomain; email@emaildomain;" rather then the expected format.

## Generating the header

The cc field is populated on a php form with fields for Subject, To, CC, and Body text POSTS to an email handling class. Inside the handler class, the From, BCC, and CC field are written into a header string using an addHeader() method.

```
function addHeader($type,$value)
{
    $this->header .= $type.":".$value.$this->eol;//eol = PHP_EOL
}
```

When the mail is actually sent it uses a send() method (that I sadly dont feel comfortable detailing too extensively) but the essential point is that it creates the full header string that looks much like this:

```
From: Company Name CC:Long Last Name, First Name <longlastname@company.com> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xb964d9146ea853337b28e6b471a8ca00x"
```

Which is added to a php mail():

```
$result = mail($this->to, $this->Subject , $this->Body, $this->header);
```

## What I have tried:

I have tried MIME encoding the header but it doesn't seem to help.

```
From: =?UTF-8?Q?Company=20Name?= Cc: =?UTF-8?Q?Long=20Last=20Name,=20First=20Name?= <longlastname@company.com> MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x4cfee11b9185861f4ba890079305ecb0x"
```

I also tried replacing the white space characters with alternatives like &nbsp or   (space) but it did not solve the issue either.

Comment: I thought: `$headers .= "CC: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";`

Comment: Php can handle simple variables inside a string without opening and closing quotes. Something like $string = "$var1"; or $string = "$var->value"; are fine. I did try having string formatting as well but that did not really work.

Comment: Try adding new line characters